# Sum of numbers of a number

Tags: java, math

Say I have the number 123

Is there a computationally efficient way of adding 1+2+3 and getting the answer back

Ideally I'd avoid division or parsing to String as I feel this can be quite inefficient.

Comment: So you want to add all the digits together?

Comment: You can't ask *this* on Code Review.  There's no code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of parsing to string.

```
int sum=0;
while(n>0)
{
    sum += n%10; // add the last digit
    n/=10;  // remove the last digit.
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, but he want to avoid division.

Comment: No, @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh, he want's something as efficient as possible and he is potentially mistaken in thinking that division is not the most efficient way.

Comment: @Gabrielus You may use recursive methods.